# Loop through watershed areas in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have X-Ray image that I want to segement fracture

i'm used:

```
L = watershed(gradmag2);
```

and :

```
Lrgb = label2rgb(L, 'jet', 'w', 'shuffle');
```

how can I loop through regions and show each region in separte image

**xray image of Tibia Bone**

[image: xray image of Tibia Bone]

Answer (score 0):

To extract one of the regions of a labeled image you can do

```
bin = L == 5;
```

`bin` will be a binary image that is true for each pixel that belongs to region 5.